# Show that the Galois group has a transposition

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials, galois-extensions

Let $f$ be polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, which has one double root and all the other roots are simple. Show that the Galois group of $f$ has a transposition.

I know that it can be shown using Dedekind's lemma, but the proof of that involves ramification theory, which I don't know yet. Can this be proved directly, or at least using some elementary methods of Galois theory?

Comment: Isn't that one double root necessarily rational? Because $\gcd(f,f')$ is linear?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Alright. So the gcd is $x-\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the double root.

Comment: What to do next?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. consider (x-1)^2 (x^3 - 3x + 1)  wouldn't its Galois group just be C_3 which has no transposition